# Is there a tool matching class name to styles automatically?

Tags: javascript, css

Is there a tool matching class name to styles automatically?

If given a HTML file and CSS file

Example:

HTML file

```
<div class="a"></div>
```

CSS file

```
.a {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: blue;
}
```

Generated like:

```
{
  a: {
    'font-size': '12px',
    'color': 'blue',
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain what you want ?

Comment: What? If you want to retrieve stylesheets with JS, see [StyleSheet Interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StyleSheet)

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What are you going to do with the result?

Comment: I am building a tool. And I need to require a tool as my dependency. Just wondering is there a npm module can help like:
`var html2css = require('html2css');
 var result = html2css('main.html', 'main.css');
`

Comment: And the `results` would be the object upper `{ a: { 'font-size': '12px', 'color': 'blue', } } `

Answer (score 0):

DIY is an option :

```js
appendCss({
  "my-class": {
    "background": "yellow",
    "padding": "10px"
  }
});

function appendCss (css) {
  var style = document.createElement("style");
  style.textContent = cssToString(css);
  document.head.appendChild(style);
}

function cssToString (css) {
  var c, p, s = "";
  for (c in css) {
    s += "." + c + "{";
    for (p in css[c]) {
      s += p + ":" + css[c][p] + ";";
    }
    s += "}";
  }
  return s;
}
```

```html
<span class="my-class">merry xmas</span>
```

Comment: Given that you've provided an answer could you edit the question to try to explain what the OP meant to ask?

Comment: Thanks for replying and sorry for late response. I add comments in my question. You may take a look. Thanks for putting your time on this.